# Windows Performance Analyzer getting N/A for memory leak in EtwD and EtwR

Tags: memory, windows-11, event-log, memory-leaks

I am having a big problem with Etw having a memory leak. I used Poolmon to find out that it seems Etw is the service that is having the leak. This leak only occurs when I run another program that I developed in C# .NET. I am trying to figure out why this occurs so I can resolve it. It takes a few days but seems like it gets worse the longer it runs. I have used a few .NET memory analyzers like DotMemory and DotTrace to try and see if it is the program itself but I don't think it is? For example I have older versions of my program running on PCs and it works fine no leaks. It seems newer PCs have this issue. My program does use PerformanceCounters to measure the amount of RAM on the PC, I am trying to disable that to see if that is somehow causing it.

Below is a screenshot of a Windows Performance Analyzer dump I made with xperf. It appear it has no useful data though? If I expand it to look at what is taking up the ~63GB of Paged RAM its just blank and starts at address 0 with seemingly no other information at all.

And If I look at the Nonpaged memory at Etwr I get basically the same result. No useful information? What else can I do to help figure out how to fix this?

Etwr WPA Screenshot:

[image: Etwr WPA Screenshot]

EtwD WPA Screenshot:

[image: EtwD WPA Screenshot]

Comment: You need to know if this is in user or system. Test while booting in Safe mode (if possible), to narrow it to Windows. If in Windows, try [Driver Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/use-driver-verifier-to-identify-issues) and see this [article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/driver-verifier-tracking-down-a-mis-behaving/f5cb4faf-556b-4b6d-95b3-c48669e4c983). Have a look also into [PoolMon Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/poolmon-examples) for advanced usage.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by user or system? I am running this on a user account on a regular Windows 11 HP PC not a VM or anything weird or special. The app that is seemingly indirectly causing this is a .exe app run on a regular windows user account. Not sure if that is what you meant.

I will try out the other things. Thank you.

Comment: I mean your program or driver.

Comment: I would initially capture a perf counter trace to see the profile of this suspected leak/memory mismanagement first. I would reboot the computer, to baseline pool memory. Check in Task Manager the size of .paged pool and non-paged pool and make a note.  Start a trace:

`typeperf "Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes" "Memory\Pool paged Bytes" -si 60 -o C:\typeperf-data.csv`

Start your application and leave it.  If you look in Task Manager, if the pool memory looks higher than you might expect. Then chart the data.  Is it linear? Does it just at a certain time? Is it predictable?

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. I ended up looking at the allocations that were actively being made to EtwR and EtwD in the lower panel of the Windows Performance analyzer and copy and pasted the massive line of .dll files that were involved with the allocations into chatgpt to parse what it was referencing. It ended up referencing something to do with the Audio Driver. I then commented out and rebuilt my app with no Audio functions and the memory leak entirely ceased to occur. Specifically it was the MediaPlayer class from .NET. I will have to figure out how to workaround this now.